# Are Database Layout Updates still used in Magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento

Deep in the Magento Layout system, there's the following code that's used to turn your package layout xml files into the specific XML needed to create your Blocks, and therefore create your pages

```
public function merge($handle)
{
    $packageUpdatesStatus = $this->fetchPackageLayoutUpdates($handle);
    if (Mage::app()->isInstalled()) {
        $this->fetchDbLayoutUpdates($handle);
    }
}
```

The second method there `fetchDbLayoutUpdates` tries to load additional XML Updates from the database with SQL queries something like this

```
SELECT `update`.`xml` FROM `core_layout_update` AS `update`
INNER JOIN `core_layout_link` AS `link` 
    ON link.layout_update_id=update.layout_update_id 
WHERE (link.store_id IN (0, '1')) 
    AND (link.area='frontend') 
    AND (link.package='default') 
    AND (link.theme='default') 
    AND (update.handle = 'default') 
ORDER BY `update`.`sort_order` ASC'
```

Both the `core_layout_update` and `core_layout_link` tables are empty in a default installation.

So, I've always assumed this is a legacy feature that predates my time with Magento.  Does anyone know if this feature is used anywhere by

1. The Magento Core Codebase
2. Any well known/prominent Extensions
3. You!

I can see why the feature's been left in place (legacy concerns and what not), but I'm curious if it's something that's been officially-ish abandoned, or if it's just vastly under utilized.

Comment: interesting thread, any ideas why it might be useful rather than xml files? Does that mean that DB layout entries override file-based?

Comment: @Jonathan: No, the DB entires just add additional handle instructions.  Handles never override, they're just applied in order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have some entries for `cms_index_index` that adds an `enterprise_banner` block. So it is used by Enterprise edition at least.

Comment: Ah ha, got it.  It looks like they're there in support of the CMS system in Community Edition as well.

Comment: Any chance you can post what entries you have there? Be interested to see.

Comment: The handle column is `cms_index_index` and the xml column is a wholly unremarkable layout update just like you would use to declare a block in any other page. In this case the block is of type `enterprise_banner/widget_banner` which is only useful if you have enterprise edition - and if you did you would have the database entries too.

Answer (score 4):

core_layout_update is related with widget instance, it seem core_layout_update has row for every widget instance that added from CMS->Widgets